# World Bank API - economy coder "wbgapi.Coder" element to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, api, dictionary

I would like to transform a wbgapi.Coder element to a dataframe. It is a dictionary and I tried the following:

```
import wbgapi as wb
import pandas as pd

a = wb.economy.coder(['Rwanda', 'Bolivia'])
type(a)
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(wb.economy.coder(['Rwanda', 'Bolivia']))
```

but get:

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Answer (score 0):

`wb.economy.coder(['Rwanda', 'Bolivia']` returns a dict of scalar values (there are no arrays for the values), so Pandas doesn't know what index to attribute to them.

This is how your keys and values look:

```py
wb.economy.coder(['Rwanda', 'Bolivia'].items()

# dict_items([('Rwanda', 'RWA'), ('Bolivia', 'BOL')])
```

So you must provide an index to the DataFrame method:

```py
pd.DataFrame(wbgapi.economy.DataFrame(), index=[0])
```

This will give you a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    Rwanda  Bolivia
0   RWA     BOL
```

Not very useful, but that's what the method you're using (`coder`) returns.

---

WBGAPI also provides a DataFrame method, which probably makes more sense if you want to analyze the countries data, and not just their names:

```py
wbgapi.economy.DataFrame()
```

You can read more about it [here](https://pypi.org/project/wbgapi/).